# How to add a condition in x-bind alpine.js in for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I want some class bindings on even and odd index of a for an loop in alpine.js

```
<template x-for="(item, index) in myForData" :key="index">
      <div class="bg-primary-500 text-white border-gray-900 rounded-lg block w-64 h-24 text-lg shadow hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 p-3" 
      :class="{ 'bg-green-500':  index % 2 == 0 }"
        </div>
</template>
```

I tried to work with modulo. Maybe some of you have a better idea ?

Comment: Can you share the css of bg-green-500 and bg-primary-500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to do a true toggle of the background values:

```html
<template x-for="(item, index) in myForData" :key="index">
      <div class=" text-white border-gray-900 rounded-lg block w-64 h-24 text-lg shadow hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 p-3" 
      :class="{ 'bg-primary-500': index % 2 === 1, 'bg-green-500':  index % 2 == 0 }"
        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: If that solved it, do you mind upvoting/accepting the answer?